# JsonProperty and lombok on Intellij

Tags: java, lombok

I'm running into an issue with my pojo created using lombok with jsonproperty annotation. It doesn't respect the json annotation. And, when i create an object using the lombok builder it uses the field names on the object instead of json property.

Could someone help see what am I missing here. I just started using lombok so im hoping something straightforward. I'm running the code on Intellij

```
@Data
@Builder
public class pojo {

 @JsonProperty("grant_type")
  private final String grantType = "xyz";

 @JsonProperty("client_id")
   private String clientId;

}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on `doesn't respect the json annotation`, probably with example? Because when I tried your class and return `pojo` in `RestController`, I can see `{"grant_type":"xyz","client_id":"AAA"}`, which seems correct to me.

Comment: pojo po = pojo.builder().clientId("673").build();   I am running this test on intellij, not sure if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

It's default behavior of `@Builder`.
If we want the builder with `setClientId`, We can add `setterPrefix = "set"` into `@Builder`.

```
@Data
@Builder(setterPrefix = "set")
public class pojo {
    @JsonProperty("grant_type")
    private final String grantType = "xyz";

    @JsonProperty("client_id")
    private String clientId;

}
```

`@Data` would generate a pair of setter/getter. But setter is a member method of pojo, not `pojoBuilder`'s.
More details of Builder is [here](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder).

Comment: Sorry, If I wasn't clear, I don't care if the builder uses fields for set. But, I want the object created using builder to respect the json annotation

pojo po = pojo.builder().clientId("673").build(); 

expected

(pojo(grant_type="xyz", client_id="673")

actual

(pojo(grantType="xyz", clientId="673")

Comment: You are calling `toString` instead of serialise to json with jackson. Should do something with `ObjectMapper` in your case

Comment: @enginner As @samabcde said, you need use `ObjectMapper` to serialize your object. `new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(pojo.builder().clientId("xxx").build())`

Comment: ah, thanks, I was using Gson for serializing, and it was the issue. Object mapper works fine.